# Couldn't write to database using the entity manager persist method

Tags: mysql, jsf, jpa, netbeans, ejb

I am about developing a small application using EJB JPA MySQL netbeans7.2,
so my application has the following goal: get the list of names and their IDs and add other names to the list.

My classes are:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.rachid.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "Employee.findAll", query = "SELECT e FROM Employee e"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Employee.findById", query = "SELECT e FROM Employee e WHERE  
e.id = :id"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Employee.findByName", query = "SELECT e FROM Employee e WHERE 
e.name = :name")})

public class Employee implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Size(max = 20)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    public Employee() {
    }

    public Employee(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Employee)) {
            return false;
        }
        Employee other = (Employee) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null &&     !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "com.rachid.entities.Employee[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }
}
```

The session bean that uses the entity is:

```
package com.rachid.session;

import com.rachid.entities.Employee;
 import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;

@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class EmployeeSessionBean {
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "EnterpriseApplication1-ejbPU")
private EntityManager em;

public List<Employee> getAllEmployees() {
    Query query = em.createNamedQuery("Employee.findAll");
    return query.getResultList();
}



// Add business logic below. (Right-click in editor and choose
// "Insert Code > Add Business Method")

public Employee updateEmployee(Employee parameter) {
    return em.merge(parameter);
}


public void addEmployee(Employee employee){
    em.persist(employee);

}

}
```

The managed bean is:

```
 package managedBeans;

 import com.rachid.entities.Employee;
 import com.rachid.session.EmployeeSessionBean;
 import java.io.Serializable;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;
 import javax.ejb.EJB;
 import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
 import javax.inject.Named;


 @Named(value = "employeeManagedBean")
 @ViewScoped
 public class EmployeeManagedBean implements Serializable {


public EmployeeManagedBean() {
}

@EJB
private EmployeeSessionBean employeeBean;

private Employee employee;

private Employee newEmployee;

private List<Employee> employees;

public List<Employee> getEmployees(){
    employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    return employeeBean.getAllEmployees();
}

public void setEmployees(List<Employee> employees) {
    this.employees = employees;
}


public void add(){
    if(newEmployee!= null){
      employeeBean.addEmployee(newEmployee);
    }

}

public String update(){
    System.out.println("***UPDATE***");
    employee = employeeBean.updateEmployee(employee);
    return "Employees List";
}

public Employee getNewEmployee() {
    return newEmployee;
}

public void setNewEmployee(Employee newEmployee) {
    this.newEmployee = newEmployee;
}

}
```

Unfortunately, when I invoke the method addEmployee in the jsf page, nothing is written to the database. I was worried about the transaction management handled by the container; that is the updates and inserts are managed by the container and it may not be written to the database immediately, so I annotate the addEmployee method (in the EJB) with the @TransationalAttribute(TransactionalAttributeType.REQUIRED) but the result still the same.

Is there anything that I am missing here in my code or my understanding of the issue's context?

(Note that I am a beginner in EJB :) )

Here are the jsf pages (an index page that shows the list and another one to add new element to the list):

index.xhtml file:

```xml
        <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
        <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
        </h:head>
        <h:body>
         Hello from Facelets
         <f:view>
          <h:form>
            <h1><h:outputText value="List"/></h1>
            <h:dataTable value="#{employeeManagedBean.employees}" var="item">
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Id"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.id}"/>
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Name"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.name}"/>
                </h:column>
            </h:dataTable>
        </h:form>
    </f:view>

    <h:form>
        <h:commandButton value="nouveau" action="ajouter.xhtml" type="submit" />
    </h:form>

</h:body>
```

ajouter.xhtml file:

```xml
   <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org  
    /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
     xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
     xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<h:body>
    <f:view>
        <h:form>
            <h1><h:outputText value="Create/Edit"/></h1>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <h:outputLabel value="Id:" for="id" />
                <h:inputText id="id" value="#{employeeManagedBean.newEmployee.id}" 
                   title="Id" 
                     required="true" requiredMessage="The Id field is required."/>

                <h:outputLabel value="Name:" for="name" />
                <h:inputText id="name" value="#{employeeManagedBean.newEmployee.name}" 
                 title="Name" />
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </f:view>

    <h:form>
        <h:commandButton value="ajouter" action="index.xhtml" type="submit" 
                         actionListener="#{employeeManagedBean.add()}" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

Comment: Did you try placing a breakpoint and walking through in debug mode?  Is this EJB method even getting called?  Perhaps there is a validation error on your form and it is preventing the JSF event from being fired?

Comment: Please don't place the whole contents of the files here. Comments from templates, imports, etc. are not necessary and clutter your post.